# Can there be 2 service in private spaces in Heroku Bonsai add-on

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to have a static website and Elasticsearch services in my app but I want them to be in private spaces. 
Is it possible to achieve this by using Docker containers? 
Because if Elasticsearch already built in, in Heroku Bonsai add-on, then my website docker container could access to it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Apps in private spaces can usually access add ons such as Bonsai.  Each app can have one or more add-ons.  If you want to maintain a private link between your app and elasticsearch with Bonsai, you would want a Private plan from bonsai, which uses VPC peering to the private space.